# Combine two separate, working queries

Tags: google-sheets-query

Trying to combine two separate, working queries, so both can be used on a single sheet.

The idea is a User selects Data for a Resource (sheet TAB), and then either: a Region (Column D) or a County (Column H). Both Region and County are Drop Down lists.

These are the Queries that work separately:

`=QUERY(indirect(B2&"!A1:H20"), "SELECT * WHERE 1=1 " &IF(A2="All Counties", "", " AND (D) = '"&A2&"' OR (D) = 'All Counties' "),3)`

`=QUERY(indirect(B2&"!A1:H20"), "SELECT * WHERE 1=1 " &IF(C2="All Regions", "", " AND (H) = '"&C2&"' OR (H) = 'All Regions' "),3)`

Working Queries are on the first 2 TABs of this [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XWrNyu9LbaXbvD92Ci7d8kwGEZElQPN-VUkg_ghTEZY/edit?usp=sharing)

I have tried to join them:
`={QUERY(indirect(B2&"!A1:H20"), "SELECT * WHERE 1=1 " &IF(A2="All Counties", "", " AND (D) = '"&A2&"' OR (D) = 'All Counties' "),3); QUERY(indirect(B2&"!A1:H20"), "SELECT * WHERE 1=1 " &IF(C2="All Regions", "", " AND (H) = '"&C2&"' OR (H) = 'All Regions' "),3)}`

Also tried a few things like this with various syntax changes:
`=QUERY(indirect(B2&"!A1:H20"), "SELECT * WHERE 1=1 " &IF(A2="All Counties", "", " AND (D) = '"&A2&"' AND (C2)="-" OR (D) = 'All Counties' "  AND (C2)="-" OR C2="All Regions", "", " AND (H) = '"&C2&"' AND (A2)="-" OR (H) = 'All Regions' AND (A2)="-" "),3)`

Also tried similar to above, but used ISBLANK(C2) type syntax.